# .htaccess conditional rewriting .html to .php

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

First to say, sorry if I'm doubleposting, but I didn't find a solution to this one.

I'm trying to rewrite my urls so that, whene I enter somepage.html it serves me somepage.php but ONLY if somepage.html doesn't exist. Anyone can help? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.html$ $1.php [L,R=301]
```

also see [Redirect requests only if the file is not found?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595005/redirect-requests-only-if-the-file-is-not-found)

Comment: sorry, but this isn't working for me... 

for example:

www.myurl.com/something.html works fine if the file is there, but if there is no file, it tries to grab (and changes url to):

www.myurl.com/emformar/domains/myurl.com/public_html/something.php

Comment: Try adding `RewriteBase   /` before the rules.
[RewriteBase docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase)

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)\.html$ $1.php [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, this was my solution.

This will check to see if there is a HTML file present, if not it will use PHP - ideal if you have migrated your website to PHP and are concerned about any 3rd party links to HTML pages

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [R=301,L

]
```