# collisions for rules in htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is my htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php #Line 1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ product.php?name=$1 #Line 2
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ product.php?name=$1 #Line 3
```

Line 1 is to remove php extension for all files
Line 2 and 3 are such that if you type website.com/ it will translate into website.com/product.php?name=something

Now, I installed a blog whose url is website.com/blog

This is interfering with the product. So instead of serving website.com/blog it gets translated to website.com/product.php?name=blog which is giving incorrect results. How can this problem be solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may find this question useful: [Redirect requests only if the file is not found?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595005/redirect-requests-only-if-the-file-is-not-found)

```
# If requested resource exists as a file or directory, skip next two rules
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 -d
RewriteRule (.*) - [S=2]
#
# Requested resource does not exist, do rewrite if it exists in /archive
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/archive/$1 -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/archive/$1 -d
RewriteRule (.*) /archive/$1 [L]
#
# Else rewrite requests for non-existent resources to /index.php
RewriteRule (.*) /index.php?q=$1 [L]
```

The following may also be of interest: [How do I ignore a directory in mod_rewrite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163302/how-do-i-ignore-a-directory-in-mod-rewrite)

Try putting this before any other rules.

```
RewriteRule ^blog - [L,NC]
```

Comment: Excellent. It works. The last rewrite rule before every thing else worked. Thank you smdrager.