# How to use multiple RewriteRules for use 3rdparty and routes at the same time?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

> The answers present in [Redirect requests only if the file is not found?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595005/redirect-requests-only-if-the-file-is-not-found) don't solve to the specific situation, for a defined real path and are routes (which will use `PATH_INFO`).

I have a `.htaccess` to add `path_info` in the `index.php` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d

RewriteRule ^(?!index\.php/.*)([a-zA-Z0-9\-\/.]+)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
```

This works perfectly with my route system that is in the `index.php`

But I want use *3rdparty* at the time, I used the following code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d

RewriteRule ^(?!(3rdparty|index\.php)/.*)(.*)$ 3rdparty/$2 [QSA,L]
```

The idea of this code is that any file or folder inside the "3rdparty" override the routes, eg. If acess `http://localhost/folder1/` it will show the contents of the file `/var/www/3rdparty/folder1/` but if the file don't exists in `3rdparty` folder, then it will use the system routes.

### Folder structure

This is an example of structure:

```
project
├── index.php
├── .htaccess
└── 3rdparty
    ├── folder1
    └── folder2
        ├── file1.html
        └── file2.html
```

I want to use other PHP files without having to access an address as `http://localhost/3rdparty/something...`

Examples (see folder structure):

- `http://example/project/folder1` shows contents from this address `http://example/project/3rdparty/folder1`
- `http://example/project/folder2` shows contents from this address `http://example/project/3rdparty/folder2/`
- `http://example/project/folder2/file1.html` shows contents from this address `http://example/project/3rdparty/folder2/file1.html`
- `http://example/project/folder2/file2.html` shows contents from this address `http://example/project/3rdparty/folder2/file2.html`
- `http://example/project/folder3/file3.html` (no-existing file in 3rdparty) shows contents from this address `http://example/project/index.php/folder3/file3.html`

The problem is that I'm not able to use both at the same time, how can I do this?

Comment: Why the downvote? I missed something in my question? Tell where wrong for me to improve question.

Comment: You are telling non-existent urls in the first rule to go to 3rdparty folder. how is the server going to know the difference?

Comment: @PanamaJack Could you help me? I just posted the code was trying to do.

Comment: Is your structure contstant? Meaning all you have is folder1 and folder2

Comment: sorry, i missunderstood. changing my answer

Comment: @PanamaJack It's just an example, I can add content in the "3rdparty" at any time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Redirect requests only if the file is not found?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/595005/redirect-requests-only-if-the-file-is-not-found)

Comment: You can't use the same logic, You will have to see if the actual requests exists.

Comment: why not simply `RewriteRule ^(?!3rdparty|index\.php)(.*)$ 3rdparty/$1 [QSA,L]` and `RewriteRule ^(?!index\.php)([\w\-\/\.]+)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]` ?

Comment: @Deadooshka Good  tip, but `\w` allow `_` (underline) in urls, I avoid this because of some SEO issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problems:

- It was adding `RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME)` at the beginning unnecessarily.
- I used `$1`, but the right was `$2` or `$3` (it depends on the order)

Fixed code (read comments):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Replace next line by / or by a folder name 
    # Example: /laravel (http://localhost/laravel)
    # Example: /cakephp (http://localhost/cakephp)
    # I used /project (http://localhost/project)

    RewriteBase /project

    # Next line allow access to static files
    # no needs type "public" in address, example:
    # http://localhost/project/css/file.css
    # http://localhost/project/js/file.js
    # http://localhost/project/images/file.jpg

    RewriteRule ^(css|js|images)/(.*)$ public/$1/$2 [QSA,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    # If the address is not equal to
    # localhost/css or localhost/js redirect to 3rdparty:

    RewriteRule ^(?!(index\.php|public|3rdparty)/.*)(.*)$ 3rdparty/$2 [QSA,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    # If no such file/folder in 3rdparty when use route system in index.php:
    RewriteRule ^(?!index\.php/.*)3rdparty/([a-zA-Z0-9\/\-.]+)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

> **Note:** Removed `\w` of example because it allow `_` (underscore)

Answer (score 1):

Going off what the what I was saying about checking if it exists and the link Alejandro posted, here is an adaption for your situation. See if this will work for you.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} [A-Z]{3,}\ /3rdparty/([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]    

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 -d
RewriteRule (.*) - [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/3rdparty/$1 -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/3rdparty/$1 -d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /3rdparty/$1 [L]

RewriteRule (.*) /index.php [QSA,L]
```