# simple nginx if statement in C

Tags: c, nginx

I have this line of code in my /etc/nginx/sites-available/default page:

```
rewrite ^/(.*)/(.*) /search.php?name=$1&last=$2
```

It accomplished what I wanted: cleaner urls for linking

example.com/john/smith is forwarded properly to the PHP GET.

But, it also destroyed all my styling and image links.

So I would like the rewrite to occur only if the first word is neither css nor image.

But I can only find if statements for GET arguments in the url not for directoies in the url like this:

```
if ($args ~* "/?param1=val1&param2=val2&") {
      rewrite ^ http://www.example.com/newparam/$arg_param1/$arg_param2? last;
}
```

Comment: I think a better solution may be to only apply the rewrite if the requested filename doesn't exist. [Take a look at this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/595005/redirect-requests-only-if-the-file-is-not-found).

Comment: @AustinBrunkhorst I would be willing to use that solution, but it seems to be for apache and my issue is getting the syntax right. Ill look for nginx solutions like that

Answer (score 1):

After following the apache solution suggested in this comment:

"I think a better solution may be to only apply the rewrite if the requested filename doesn't exist. Take a look at this question. [Redirect requests only if the file is not found?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595005/redirect-requests-only-if-the-file-is-not-found) "

I converted that functionality to nginx and got:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    if (-f $request_filename) {
            break;
    }
    rewrite ^/(.*)/(.*) /search.php?name=$1&last=$2
}
```

This makes the url rewrite only if there is no file found at the given directory path