# Proxy requests only if the file is not found?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, reverse-proxy

I'm looking for an equivalent of [Redirect requests only if the file is not found?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595005/redirect-requests-only-if-the-file-is-not-found) where instead of redirecting, I want it to do a ProxyPass to another server if a file is missing.

This didn't work too well since it will not handle requests that do not end with "/" e.g. https://site.trajano.net/trajano which goes to the proxy and redrects instead.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule (.*) - [L]
RewriteRule (.*) https://trajano.github.io/%{REQUEST_URI} [P]
```

I tried the following from a different answer as well which works slightly better but what happens is it redirects to github rather than proxy.

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 -d
RewriteRule (.*) - [S=2]
#
# Requested resource does not exist, do rewrite if it exists in /archive
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/archive/$1 -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/archive/$1 -d
RewriteRule (.*) /archive/$1 [L]
#
# Else
RewriteRule (.*) https://trajano.github.io/%{REQUEST_URI} [P]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both `mod_rewrite` and `mod_proxy` need to be enabled.  Place the following in a `VirtualHost` block (not inside a `Directory` directive or anything other than `VirtualHost`):

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/
RewriteRule (.*) - [L]
#
# Else proxy
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ https://trajano.github.io/$1 [P,QSA]
ProxyPassReverse / https://trajano.github.io/
```

The first Rewrite block handles files and directories that exist in which case it returns the original file block.

The next rewrite rule will handle the proxies.  The `ProxyPassReverse` ensures that the `Location` being returned is rewritten back to the local server rather than the proxied server.

Comment: This worked great, but only if you have a request in the url. If you want it to work for "/" then you will need to add an additional RewriteCond under `RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 -d` and add `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/`

Comment: not sure what you mean, but you can make an edit