# If existing file, redirect to a certain file, else redirect to 404 from htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-404

I have this tree:

```
libs/
html/
app/
uploads/
    files/
    images/
        male.png
        female.png
    .htaccess
    download.php
.htaccess
index.php
```

/.htaccess has this content:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule ^ index.php [END,L]
</IfModule>
```

I want /uploads/.htaccess to:

- redirect to download.php

  - if existent file, but not this .htaccess or download.php
- redirect 404

  - if don't match existent file
  - or match .htaccess or download.php
  - or match existent folder

Examples:

```
www.example.com/uploads - redirect 404
www.example.com/uploads/files - redirect 404
www.example.com/uploads/images- redirect 404
www.example.com/uploads/.htaccess - redirect 404
www.example.com/uploads/download.php - redirect 404
www.example.com/uploads/nonexistentfile - redirect 404

www.example.com/uploads/images/male.php - redirect download.php
www.example.com/uploads/images/female.php - redirect download.php
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have asked the question also on serverfault.com and I got an expected answer:
https://serverfault.com/questions/975415/if-file-exists-redirect-to-a-certain-file-else-redirect-to-404-from-htaccess/975451?noredirect=1#comment1269343_975451

Answer (score 0):

The discussion below should help you a bit:
[Redirect requests only if the file is not found?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595005/redirect-requests-only-if-the-file-is-not-found)

```
# If requested resource exists as a file or directory go to it
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule (.*) - [L]
#Alternatively the code above redirects where you want

# Else rewrite requests for non-existent resources to /404.php
RewriteRule (.*) /404.php?q=$1 [L]
```

Comment: I want the opposite. Redirect to download.php if file is found.